# save a list of Keras models

Tags: python-3.x, keras, pickle

I am using Keras 2.0.6 to build models. I keep several models in a list called `keras_models`. So instead just saving one model, I want to save the entire list of models to a pickle file like below:

```
joblib.dump(keras_models, 'keras_models.pkl')
```

This approach works fine when I have a list of sklearn random forest model and a list of ridge regression models. However, I got the following errors with a list of keras models. Any idea what was wrong? Is there a way to save the entire list of keras models to one file? Thanks!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _getattribute(obj, name, allow_qualname)
    271         try:
--> 272             obj = getattr(obj, subpath)
    273         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lock'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_global(self, obj, name)
    910             module = sys.modules[module_name]
--> 911             obj2 = _getattribute(module, name, allow_qualname=self.proto >= 4)
    912         except (ImportError, KeyError, AttributeError):

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _getattribute(obj, name, allow_qualname)
    274             raise AttributeError("Can't get attribute {!r} on {!r}"
--> 275                                  .format(name, obj))
    276     return obj

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'lock' on <module '_thread' (built-in)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e038764ff1dd> in <module>()
    145 #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    146 
--> 147 joblib.dump(keras_models, 'keras_models_20170928.pkl')
    148 
    149 keras_metric_df.to_pickle('keras_metric_20170928.pkl')

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in dump(value, filename, compress, protocol, cache_size)
    481     elif is_filename:
    482         with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
--> 483             NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
    484     else:
    485         NumpyPickler(filename, protocol=protocol).dump(value)

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in dump(self, obj)
    410         if self.proto >= 4:
    411             self.framer.start_framing()
--> 412         self.save(obj)
    413         self.write(STOP)
    414         self.framer.end_framing()

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    477         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    478         if f is not None:
--> 479             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    480             return
    481 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_list(self, obj)
    772 
    773         self.memoize(obj)
--> 774         self._batch_appends(obj)
    775 
    776     dispatch[list] = save_list

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _batch_appends(self, items)
    796                 write(MARK)
    797                 for x in tmp:
--> 798                     save(x)
    799                 write(APPENDS)
    800             elif n:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    522 
    523         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 524         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    525 
    526     def persistent_id(self, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    625 
    626         if state is not None:
--> 627             save(state)
    628             write(BUILD)
    629 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    477         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    478         if f is not None:
--> 479             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    480             return
    481 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    812 
    813         self.memoize(obj)
--> 814         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    815 
    816     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    838                 for k, v in tmp:
    839                     save(k)
--> 840                     save(v)
    841                 write(SETITEMS)
    842             elif n:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    477         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    478         if f is not None:
--> 479             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    480             return
    481 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_list(self, obj)
    772 
    773         self.memoize(obj)
--> 774         self._batch_appends(obj)
    775 
    776     dispatch[list] = save_list

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _batch_appends(self, items)
    799                 write(APPENDS)
    800             elif n:
--> 801                 save(tmp[0])
    802                 write(APPEND)
    803             # else tmp is empty, and we're done

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    522 
    523         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 524         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    525 
    526     def persistent_id(self, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    625 
    626         if state is not None:
--> 627             save(state)
    628             write(BUILD)
    629 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    477         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    478         if f is not None:
--> 479             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    480             return
    481 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    812 
    813         self.memoize(obj)
--> 814         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    815 
    816     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    838                 for k, v in tmp:
    839                     save(k)
--> 840                     save(v)
    841                 write(SETITEMS)
    842             elif n:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    522 
    523         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 524         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    525 
    526     def persistent_id(self, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    625 
    626         if state is not None:
--> 627             save(state)
    628             write(BUILD)
    629 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    477         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    478         if f is not None:
--> 479             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    480             return
    481 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    812 
    813         self.memoize(obj)
--> 814         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    815 
    816     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    838                 for k, v in tmp:
    839                     save(k)
--> 840                     save(v)
    841                 write(SETITEMS)
    842             elif n:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    522 
    523         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 524         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    525 
    526     def persistent_id(self, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    625 
    626         if state is not None:
--> 627             save(state)
    628             write(BUILD)
    629 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    477         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    478         if f is not None:
--> 479             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    480             return
    481 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    812 
    813         self.memoize(obj)
--> 814         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    815 
    816     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    838                 for k, v in tmp:
    839                     save(k)
--> 840                     save(v)
    841                 write(SETITEMS)
    842             elif n:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    522 
    523         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 524         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    525 
    526     def persistent_id(self, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    596                     "args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class")
    597             args = args[1:]
--> 598             save(cls)
    599             save(args)
    600             write(NEWOBJ)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py in save(self, obj)
    278             return
    279 
--> 280         return Pickler.save(self, obj)
    281 
    282 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    477         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    478         if f is not None:
--> 479             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    480             return
    481 

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_type(self, obj)
    964         elif obj is type(...):
    965             return self.save_reduce(type, (...,), obj=obj)
--> 966         return self.save_global(obj)
    967 
    968     dispatch[FunctionType] = save_global

/usr/lib/python3.4/pickle.py in save_global(self, obj, name)
    913             raise PicklingError(
    914                 "Can't pickle %r: it's not found as %s.%s" %
--> 915                 (obj, module_name, name))
    916         else:
    917             if obj2 is not obj:

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_thread.lock'>: it's not found as _thread.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model),

> It is not recommended to use pickle or cPickle to save a Keras model.

If it is truly important that all of your models be stored in one file, I recommend implementing your own saving/loading methods. You can use [hickle](https://github.com/telegraphic/hickle) to save the weight matrices in HDF5 format instead of pickle's JSON-like format. (HDF5 is more efficient when storing large matrices.)